# Finding values in equation

Tags: calculus

So I'm trying to find $a$. So I plugged in $t$ as $0$, and T as $25$.  I simplified it down but now I've got $25 = a + b$ ...how can I find $a$?

Q: The temperature, $T$, in degrees Celsius, of an object put into a $200$ degree oven is given as a function of time, $t$, in minutes, by:

$T = a(1 - e^{-kt}) + b$

(i) If the object starts at a temperature of $15$ degrees Celsius, find the values of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$T(t)=a(1-e^{-kt})+b\iff T(t)=a\left(1-\frac{1}{e^{kt}}\right)+b$$

Hence we calculate $T(0):$

$$T(0)=a\left(1-\frac{1}{e^0}\right)+b=b$$

Now we calculate $$\lim_{t\to\infty}T(t)=\lim_{t\to\infty}a\left(1-\frac{1}{e^{kt}}\right)+b=a\left(1-0\right)+b=a+b$$

So if $T(t)$ models the temperature of an object with an initial temperature of $15^{\circ}$ after it is put into a $200^{\circ}$ oven, then $T(0)$ should be the temperature of the object the moment it is put into oven, i.e. the initial temperature of the object.

Therefore, conclude that $$T(0)=b=15$$

Now, we argue that $\lim_{t\to\infty}T(t)$ represents the temperature of the object after an arbitrarily long period of time in the $200^{\circ}$ oven. The object's temperature should raise until it matches that of its surroundings (because of thermodynamical considerations), so the long term behavior of the temperature of the object should be the same as the $200^{\circ}$ oven, namely $$\lim_{t\to\infty}T(t)=\text{Temperature of oven}=200^{\circ}$$

Hence $a+b=200$ and $b=15$, this implies $a=185$.

Comment: OOoh ok....how would I do this part? (ii) If the temperature of the object is initially increasing at 2 degrees Celsius per minute, find the value of k.

Comment: that's the rate of change it's decreasing?

Comment: I guess I'd differentiate then but what would I do after?

Comment: Okay. I'd first have to plug in the values of a and b right?

Comment: sorry, how do I differentiate the e^-kt part? With the k and the t? how do I treat them because I'd need them in the deriviative of the function

Comment: i'm confused about the part after the last equals sign..what is that?

Comment: that part about the 0−185(−)+0 . is that the derivative?

Comment: the derivative of the expoential would be -ke^-kt?

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the beginning you have $T=15$, $t=0$. In the limit You should have $T=200$ and $t=\infty$. Plug these and you can solve for a and $b$. Also by plugging the first you get $b=15$ not $a+b=25$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer pertains to

> how would I do this part? (ii) If the temperature of the object is initially increasing at >2 degrees Celsius per minute, find the value of k

The equation is established to be
$$T = 185(1-e^{-kt}) + 15$$
If the temperature is increasing at $2$ degrees celcius initially, then $\frac{dT}{dt} = 2$ at $t=0$.
Additionally,
$$T = 185- 185e^{-kt} + 15 = 200-185e^{-kt}$$
so
$$\frac{dT}{dt} = -185(-k)e^{-kt}$$
Setting $t=0$ means that $\frac{dT}{dt} = 185k$, and $\frac{dT}{dt} = 2$, so $185k = 2$ or $k=\frac{2}{185}$